# call method on returned value of `__getattribute__`

Tags: python, methods, getattribute

I'm trying to programmatically call a particular method on attributes of a class, `Outer` calling the `step` method on the `Inner` attribute below.  I need to do this because I'll have a variable number of attributes that implement the step method.

```
class Inner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def step(self):
        self.a += 1

class Outer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner = Inner()
        self.step_attrs = []
        for attr in self.__dir__():
            if hasattr(self.__getattribute__(attr), 'step'):
                self.step_attrs.append(attr)
    def step(self):
        for attr in self.step_attrs:
            self.__getattribute__(attr).__getattribute__('step')()
        

outer = Outer()
print(outer.inner.a)
outer.step()
print(outer.inner.a)
```

This code throws: `TypeError: expected 1 argument, got 0`

If I changed the last line in the `Outer().step` method to

```
self.__getattribute__(attr).__getattribute__('step')(self.__getattribute__(attr))
```

it fails with `TypeError: step() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i got you right, you need somethig like this :

```
class Inner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def step(self):
        self.a += 1

class Outer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner = Inner()
        self.step_attrs = [i for i in self.__dict__ if hasattr(self,"step")]
        print(self.step_attrs)

    def step(self):
        for j in self.step_attrs:
            getattr(self,j).step()

outer = Outer()
print(outer.inner.a)
outer.step()
print(outer.inner.a)
```

Result :

```
['inner']
0
1
```

Comment: Yep, this solves it.  Oddly, if you change `getattr(self,j).step()` to `self.__getattribute__(self, j).step()`, which is something I tried, it fails.   I don't really understand why.

Comment: The list comprehension needs to be `self.__dict__ if hasattr(getattr(self, attr), "step")`